# Why does glossaries-extra "\glsxtrshot" is not working while just few lines above in the same paragraph, it does?

Tags: packages, glossaries-extra

[image]
[image]
As shown in the pics, the \glstrshort doesn't work all the time, more unfortunately, it fails most of the time.
Looking at the example of PPD, it works on the top of the first pic, but fails at the top of the second one.

It only returns me the common warning:

> l.94     \item Elite mean values of \glsxtrshot
> {PPD} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
> \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type` I' and the
> correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll
> forget about whatever was undefined.

And I asked GPT, still don't have a clue to fix it.

Comment: well the glossaries commands are sometimes not really readable, but `glsxtrshot` is not the same as `glsxtrshort`, the first is missing an `r`.

Comment: sorry for asking such a stupid Question. 
However, I can't find the spelling mistake.
Thanks for saving my day.